# Срабатывание скрипта при определённом размере браузера

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Всем привет, нужно что бы скрипт:

```js
 
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#features').wowBook({height : 500, width  : 800, pageNumbers: 0, 
            }
        }).css({'display':'none', 'margin':'auto'}).fadeIn(1000);

 if ( $(window).width() < 768 {
 
 }
```

срабатывал при определённых размерах окна браузера, я нашел скрипт но не могу сделать его рабочим, в  js  полный ноль,  как я понимаю данный код просто нужно выстроить в правильном порядке, есть знающие люди?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте комментарии к коду.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   //Начало функции проверки, что документ загружен. Должен закрываться тегами }); соответственно.
    $('#features').wowBook({height : 500, width  : 800, pageNumbers: 0, //Тут ещё что-то было у Вас после запятой, есть закрывающий тег }. Надо аккуратнее модифицировать часть кода, которые Вы откуда-то взяли. 
                }
            }).css({'display':'none', 'margin':'auto'}).fadeIn(1000);

if ($(window).width() < 768 { // if имеет синтаксис if (выполнение условия){выполнение действия}

     } // Нет закрывающего тега функции ready документа.
```

У Вас должно получиться подобное:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 768) {
        $('#features').wowBook({height : 500, width  : 800, pageNumbers: 0}).css({'display':'none', 'margin':'auto'}).fadeIn(1000);
    } });
```

Так же полагаю, что при изменении размера экрана данные тоже должны меняться, а не только при загрузке документа.
 По-этому можно добавить функцию изменения размера.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 768) {
        $('#features').wowBook({height : 500, width  : 800, pageNumbers: 0}).css({'display':'none', 'margin':'auto'}).fadeIn(1000);
    } });
```

Comment: видимо я совсем безнадежен, у меня блок уменьшился но все его свойства пропали, то есть картинки анимации и т.д. "

Comment: @Knurl360259 добавьте разметку html в вопрос, чтобы понять что у Вас там не так.